How does Nietzsche's Übermensch actually behaves?
Newbie in philosophy here.
In understand that the Nietzchean Übermensch is strong enough to build his own morality.
My question is : how does a Nietzchean Übermensch actually behaves ?
Some examples of questions I am asking myself :

Is it required to literally spend 10 years in a cave he reflecting on his own morality ?

How do you recognize an Übermensch if you you pass one on the street ?

When an Übermensch goes to buy bread, does he pay? The indicated price?

Does an Übermensch accept the condition of use to create an account on stack exchange ?

Does he get a job to earn money ?

Is he interested in science ? Will he study astrophysics, biology, etc ?

Does he declare his revenues and pay the taxes ?


Are the bad guys of Sade Nietzschean Übermensch ?
They were invented almost one century before Nietzche's Zarathoustra, but Juliette starts from the same premise : if there are no Gods, the morality (the concepts of good and evil) have to be found in each individual's will.

Way too many questions here, but I suspect the answer to all of them is the same: Nietzsche didn't imply any specific answer and left this to the individual.

To understand better what Nietzsche means one should read at least the preface and some books of Nietzsche's "Thus Spoke Zarathustra" before. Have you done this already?

If the morality is to be found in each Übermensch's will then why do you expect a uniform set of instructions on how they are to behave? To each Übermensch their own.

How does Nietzsche's Übermensch actually behave?
Given that the Übermensch decides on and develops its own goals and values, then no particular set of behaviors can be predicted or is expected.  The U need not adhere to any external set of values, but it might end up having similar ones, so the answer to most of your questions is 'maybe yes maybe no'. And there's no injunction to go off to a cave, though it seems Nietzshe thought to reach this state one would need to introspect and mull quite a bit.

Nietzsche’s Best Life: The Ten Greatest Attributes of the Ubermensch, & a Comparison to Aristotle’s Virtuous Person - Randall Firestone
https://file.scirp.org/Html/8-1650804_78855.htm

ABSTRACT - The paper first outlines the 10 primary attributes of the Ubermensch, Nietzsche’s ideal person, with numerous quotations. Those attributes are self-determina- tion, creativity, becoming, overcoming, discontent, flexibility, self-mastery, self- confidence, cheerfulness, and courage. The paper then compares Nietzsche’s Ubermensch with Aristotle’s virtuous person. Nietzsche describes more of an attitude towards life and a process of living which are similar to a means as compared to Aristotle’s objective character traits which are goals or ends in themselves. The paper concludes that Nietzsche does a better job of describing the best human life―one that is dynamic, passionate, and unique; consisting of self-growth and creativity; and filled with new experiences, insights, and adventures.


Most critics agree that the ubermensch is one of Nietzsche’s solutions to his version of nihilism. Specifically, in a world where God does not seem to exist, where there is not any absolute right or wrong nor absolute good or evil and therefore there are no clear standards from which to judge actions as moral or immoral, and where there is no clear purpose, meaning, or aim to life, how is one to conduct their life and view it as meaningful and important?


“God is Dead” … and how much must collapse now that this faith has been undermined because it was built upon this faith, propped up by it, grown into it; for example, the whole of our European morality. ( GS, V, 343: p. 279 ) Imagine a being like nature, wasteful beyond measure, indifferent beyond measure, without purposes and consideration, without mercy and justice, fertile and desolate and uncertain at the same time; imagine indifference itself as a power―how could you live according to this indifference? ( BGE, I, 9: p. 205 )


Although the ubermensch is one of Nietzsche’s answers, it is far from his only answer because his ideal person takes different forms in his various books. For example, the master or nobleman of Beyond Good and Evil, the sovereign individual in On the Genealogy of Morals, the character Zarathustra in Thus Spoke Zarathustra, the Dionysian combined with the Apollinian in The Birth of Tragedy, and the free spirit in Human, All Too Human are additional descriptions of the person whom Nietzsche suggests we strive to become. The philosopher, too, is at times portrayed as this ideal person. I will view the character traits which Nietzsche deemed desirable and as enunciated throughout his books as portraying the multiple attributes of the ubermensch, the ideal or higher person whom he only occasionally referred to by this name.

The Hero's Journey - Experiencing Death and Rebirth
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tssOG2rS1AA
In the Loki series on Disney Plus the main character Loki comes to the point where he says, "I know what I want. I know what kind of God I want to be!" Loki has some power to control his story, but he does not have ultimate power to do so. The Ubermensch would write his own story as a hero living the ideal life, a life worth living over and over for eternity. There is no objective ethical standard of behavior for a hero who is experiencing cooperation and conflict inside the human drama. The hero and villain both express self mastery, and the capacity for self sacrifice, based on their respective desires, intentions, and values in the drama.
